# Azure media player not playing videos

Tags: azure, video, browser, media

Please see the HTML Below. This is being used to play videos uploaded to Azure.

It only works on a couple of pc's, but in general it fails. For example latest Firefox and IE11.

Any tips, fixes, would be great ...

regards,
Jon.

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<base href="http://www.example.com/doc/" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta name="description" content=" " />
<meta name="Content-Language" content="en" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="Privat" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-100" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>E-Experience Video</title>
```

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.6.2/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/1.6.2/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
<video id="asmmedia" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin " controls autoplay width="740" height="428" poster="" data-setup='{"logo": { "enabled": false}, "techOrder": ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "silverlightSS", "html5"], "nativeControlsForTouch": false}' tabindex="0">
    <source src="http://asmsoutheastasia%2Estreaming%2Emediaservices%2Ewindows%2Enet%2Fc75725e6%2D18c7%2D422a%2Dbe38%2D8b03ef4d11f7%2FJC%2DAC%2D297%2DV1%2DCalibration+%2D+Gantry+Axis+%2Eism%2FManifest" type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" />
    <p class="amp-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video</p>
</video>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your manifest is 404ing right now, do you have a repro URL for this issue?